# Emulating a fixed sidebar template issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

am trying to emulate this theme:

http://themetrust.com/demos/ink/?project=the-city-of-samba

But instead make the blog post always remain centered in the right hand side (space outside of the fixed sidebar) and have the blog post be of a % width.

I currently have this set up on my site, but am using a percentage based sidebar which looks awful.

Here is a JSfiddle recreating in basic terms the theme from above:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uyv6w/4/

All i am after is to make that grey inner div always remain centered inside the red content div.

Incase JSFiddle goes down and for future ref:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
  position: fixed;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
}

#inner {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: #888;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't advise the extensive mixing of pixels and percentages. This will make responsiveness more difficult further down the line. Also if you were to make your left sidebar a percentage width that would make positioning your inner div child's play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just 2 properties to change in ordre to make this work the way you want :

```
#content {
    /* width: 100%; */
    margin-left: 100px; /* the width of you sidebar.
                            Since #content is a div, a block-level element
                            , its width will be automatically 100%
                            , minus the margins */
    background-color: #f00;
}

#inner {
    width: 60%;
    /* margin-left: 150px; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; /* having margin-left & right set to auto will center your div.
                            you could also use "margin: 0 auto" */
    background-color: #888;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

I have updated you JSFiddle example here : **http://jsfiddle.net/Uyv6w/5/**

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/requv/1/edit

if you set body, html (and the container) to height 100%, it will not be able to to scroll.
the height should be more then 100%.

Comment: Fair point but seeing as it doesn't answer the question it belongs as a comment.